# Creating a function that returns a generic function

Tags: c#, generics, events, delegates, task

`obj1.Event` takes in `Func<CancellationToken,Task>`.

This works:

```
obj1.Event += async _ =>
{
    try
    {
        await function1(stoppingToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.ToString());
    }
};
```

How would one create a function that returns a generic function ex?

```
obj1.Event += HandleEvent(function1(stoppingToken))
obj2.Event += HandleEvent(function2(stoppingToken))
obj3.Event += HandleEvent(function3(stoppingToken))
```

Something close to this perhaps but this does not work!

```
public Func<CancellationToken, Task> HandleEvent<T???>(Func<T> ????)
{
    return func;
}
```

Comment: What does `HandleEvent` do? i.e. how would you convert a function with no parameters that returns `T` into a function that takes a `CancellationToken` and returns `Task`?

Comment: Ideally HandleEvent would takin in any of about 10 functions, each with a CancellationToken as a parameter, and return Func<CancellationToken, Task> to the event.

Comment: Jonathan, can you show me what the function signature should look like?

Comment: So all the functions you want to pass return `Task` also? Is the purpose of `HandleEvent` just to wrap the try..catch?

Comment: Essentially I just want an efficient way to pass 10-20 different functions all with a single CancellationToken as their only parameter  into an event that requires this Func<CancellationToken,Task>. I assumed some type of generic delegate might be the most efficient approach if I could figure it out!

Comment: `Func<CancellationToken, Task>` _is_ a function that accepts a single `CancellationToken` as their only parameter. The caveat being that it must return a `Task`. Do all your functions return a `Task`?

Comment: Yes! They all take in a CancellationToken and return a Task. The only difference are the function names and what gets run. Considering this I was hoping I could 'attach' them to the objects event in an identical manner. Something LIKE obj1.Event += HandleEvent(function1(stoppingToken))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions all accept a single `CancallationToken` parameter and return a `Task` it should be a simple as this:

```
obj1.Event += function1;
obj2.Event += function2;
obj3.Event += function3;
```

Note that when `Event` is invoked, it will pass it's own `CancellationToken` into your functions.

If you want to pass the `stoppingToken` instance instead, you can create closures as so:

```
obj1.Event += _ => function1(stoppingToken);
obj2.Event += _ => function2(stoppingToken);
obj3.Event += _ => function3(stoppingToken);
```

And if you need extra code to be invoked (e.g. your `try..catch` in the question), you could do this:

```
public Func<CancellationToken, Task> HandleEvent(Func<CancellationToken, Task> func)
{
    return async cancellationToken =>
    {
        try
        {
            await func(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

// Using token from Event
obj1.Event += HandleEvent(function1);
obj2.Event += HandleEvent(function2);
obj3.Event += HandleEvent(function3);

// Using stoppingToken
obj1.Event += HandleEvent(_ => function1(stoppingToken));
obj2.Event += HandleEvent(_ => function2(stoppingToken));
obj3.Event += HandleEvent(_ => function3(stoppingToken));
```